# Mongoose: Saving an instance of my Model creates two entries in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My Code:

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
  aktuell: {N7:String, Auftragsnr:String},
  historie : [new Schema({
                date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
                changed: {N7:String, Auftragsnr:String},
                deleted: { type: Boolean, default: false }
             }, {_id:false})]
}, { strict: false });

createIP = function(req, res) {
    var ip = new IP ({
                      aktuell:     req.body.aktuell,
                      historie:    [
                          {
                            date: nowObj, 
                            changed: req.body.aktuell
                          }
                      ]
    });

    ip.save(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            res.send({status:err});
            return;
      } else {
            res.send({ status: 'OK', ip:ip });
      }
    });
}
```

I expect it to create such entry in my DB:

```
{ _id: 54181fc0c5b9c1c7294ef510,
    historie: 
    [ { deleted: false,
        changed: [Object],
        date: Tue Sep 16 2014 13:32:16 GMT+0200 (CEST) 
    } ],
    aktuell: { Auftragsnr: '12', N7: '123132' } }
```

But in addition to above object literal an additional `historie` object gets created with its own `ObjectId`. This is why I used `{_id:false}` in my model. I also declared my array as new Schema as advised by the Mongoose Docs. I am out of knowlodge, I tried so much. How to get rid of this bug?

A console.log(ip) shows that indeed two object literals are passed by mongoose to mongoDD, one with an empty `aktuell` object, and one with a filled one. Also the changed object behaves strangely. What is going on here?

```
Im listening on port 9000
Connected to Database
POST - /ip/create
{ __v: 0,
  _id: 54182c3bd9d529df6085f853,
  historie: 
   [ { deleted: false,
       changed: {},
       date: Tue Sep 16 2014 14:25:31 GMT+0200 (CEST) } ],
  aktuell: {} }
IP created
POST /ip/create/ 200 25.763 ms - 128
POST - /ip/create
{ __v: 0,
  _id: 54182c3bd9d529df6085f854,
  historie: 
   [ { deleted: false,
       changed: [Object],
       date: Tue Sep 16 2014 14:25:31 GMT+0200 (CEST) } ],
  aktuell: { Auftragsnr: '14', N7: 'qweqw' } }
IP created
POST /ip/create/ 200 23.870 ms - 214
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want an `id` on your nested documents and don't want to access them outside your ip object you don't need to create another schema for it. A new schema usually means a new collection and a reference to it. Instead, just have it be nested:

```
var IpSchema = new Schema({
    aktuell: {
        N7: { type: String },
        Auftragsnr: { type: String },
    },
    historie: [
        {
            _id: false,
            date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
            changed: {
                N7: { type: String },
                Auftragsnr: { type: String },
            },
            deleted: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        }
    ],
});
```

Think this will also solve your problem, let me know.

Comment: Your data structure is nice. Still , fyi, the other worked fine as well! The root-cause of the problem: Turns out it was due to a preflight header request "OPTIONS" from angular before the actual "POST" request had been made. My quest continues in findind undocumented features and pitfalls of angular and mongoose.

Comment: Ok I see. Hope the other issue will gets solved then.